# Did someone ever refer to Patrick Jane as Mentalist?

Tags: the-mentalist

The original intro of the TV show The Mentalist defines a mentalist as follows:

> **Mentalist**
>   /'men-tə-list/ noun
>   Someone who uses mental acuity, hypnosis and/or suggestion.
>   A master manipulator of thoughts and behavior.

However, I can not recall if Patrick Jane was ever referred to by someone (other than himself) as *the Mentalist* (in canon).

**Did someone ever call or refer to Patrick Jane as *the Mentalist*?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least once, *but it was a hallucination*. In [Devil's Cherry](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2402471/combined) (2nd episode of season 5), Jane imagines he's talking to his daughter Charlotte after drinking some belladonna tea, and this dialogue unfolds:

> *Jane:* What are you hiding?
>
> *Charlotte:* You tell me. You're the mentalist.
>
> *Jane:* I never said I was a mentalist.
>
> *Charlotte:* Spooky.

**Edit:** As for an example that *actually* happens, in [Pink Champagne on Ice](http://thementalist.wikia.com/wiki/Pink_Champagne_on_Ice) (season 4, episode 19), Jane talks to a magician (Jack) he used to work with, where this is said:

> *Jane:* Last time I saw you was 16 years ago, when you opened for me in Kansas City, and for what it's worth, you don't look a day older.
>
> *Jack:* Well, thank you, but you're mistaken, Patrick. It's you who opened for me.
>
> *Jane:*  Your memory's going.
>
> *Jack:* ***Mentalists.*** Big talkers, no skills.

[And Jack is mocking Jane rather than talking about himself. He's a *magician*, not a mentalist.]

Comment: Very nice answer! However, since he is hallucinating this conversation, he basically is referring to himself as a mentalist. I was looking for an instance where someone else does.

Comment: @LarsEbert Edited.